# how to get site users,groups, group users on each sub site of SharePoint 2013 site collection by power-shell script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

#Using Get-SPSite 
function global:Get-SPSite($url)
 {
    return new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
 }

function global:Get-SPWeb($url)
{
  $site= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
        if($site -ne $null)
            {
               $web=$site.OpenWeb();      
            }
    return $web
}

$URL="http://u************"

     $site = Get-SPSite $URL

     #Write the Header to "Tab Separated Text File"
        "Site Name`t  URL `t Group Name `t User Name" | out-file "C:\Users\s-US_SC_SSPDev_Admin\Documents\VenuPscripts\CSVFiles\test5.csv"

     #Iterate through all Webs
      foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
      {
        Write-Host "Site: ":$web -ForegroundColor Red;
        #Write the Header to "Tab Separated Text File"
        "$($web.title) `t $($web.URL) `t  `t  `t `t " | out-file "C:\Users\s-US_SC_SSPDev_Admin\Documents\VenuPscripts\CSVFiles\test5.csv" -append

         $siteUsers = $web.SiteUsers
         $siteUsers.Count

            #Write-Host "SiteUsers: ":$siteUsers -ForegroundColor red;
         foreach($user in $siteUsers) 
            {  
                #Exclude Built-in User Accounts
                if(($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "nt authority\authenticated users") -and ($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "sharepoint\system") -and ($User.name.ToLower() -ne "Everyone") -and ($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "nt authority\local service"))
                {



                            $permissionInfo = $web.GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo($user.name)
                            $roles = $permissionInfo.RoleAssignments
                            #write-host "Now checking the permissions of the user "  $user  " " "in the site " $web.Url
                        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $roles.Count; $i++)
                        {
                            $bRoles = $roles[$i].RoleDefinitionBindings
                            foreach ($roleDefinition in $bRoles)
                            {
                                 if ($roles[$i].Member.ToString().Contains('\'))
                                {
                                "`t  `t  `t  $($user.name)" | out-file "C:\Users\s-US_SC_SSPDev_Admin\Documents\VenuPscripts\CSVFiles\test5.csv" -append 

                                write-host "The User "  $user  " has direct permissions "  $roleDefinition.Name
                                }

                            }


                        }
                    }

            }                            



             #Get all Groups and Iterate through   
             foreach ($group in $Web.groups)
             {                    

             #Write-Host "Groups: ":$group -ForegroundColor green;
                    "`t  `t $($Group.Name) `t   `t `t " | out-file "C:\Users\s-US_SC_SSPDev_Admin\Documents\VenuPscripts\CSVFiles\test5.csv" -append
                    #Iterate through Each User in the group
                           foreach ($user in $group.users)
                            {
                            #Write-Host "Groups: ":$user -ForegroundColor white;
                               #Exclude Built-in User Accounts
                        #if(($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "nt authority\authenticated users") -and ($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "sharepoint\system") -and ($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "nt authority\local service"))
                        #{
                                    "`t  `t  `t  $($user.name)" | out-file "C:\Users\s-US_SC_SSPDev_Admin\Documents\VenuPscripts\CSVFiles\test5.csv" -append
                       #  }
                            }
             }


       }

    #write-host "Report Generated at C:\Users\s-US_SC_SSPDev_Admin\Documents\VenuPscripts\CSVFiles\test5.csv"
```

am facing this error

> Exception calling "GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo" with "1"
>   argument(s): "The user does not exist or is not unique." At
>   C:\Users\s-us_sc_drspint_farm\Videos\get_users.ps1:49 char:14 +
>   $permissionInfo = $web.GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo($AddUSername) +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ +
>   CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException –

Comment: am facing this error
**********************




Exception calling "GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo" with "1" argument(s): "The user does not exist or is not unique."
At C:\Users\s-us_sc_drspint_farm\Videos\get_users.ps1:49 char:14
+                             $permissionInfo = $web.GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo($AddUSername)
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException

Answer (score 0):

This script helps you to get the users by groups in a SharePoint site collection,

```
 $site = Get-SPSite <Provide Site Collection URL here>
        $web = $site.OpenWeb()
        $groups = $web.sitegroups

        foreach ($grp in $groups) {
            "Group: " + $grp.name;
            $groupName = $grp.name
            write-host "Group: " $groupName   -foregroundcolor green
            foreach ($user in $grp.users) {
                    "User: " + $user.name
                    write-host "User " $user.UserLogin   -foregroundcolor red
            }
        }
```

Comment: but i want based on each sub site loop in site collection.

i should write sub site url .